# Write a for loop to create 5 randomly generated dataframes of length 100,200,500,800, and 1000, and print each of the dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, random

I've been trying to work through this small R prompt, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I haven't used R in a few years, so I'm trying to get back into the flow of things. Here's my code:

```
y <- 5
loopValues <- c(100,200,500,800,1000)
dataframesq3 <- vector("list", y)

for (i in 1:y) {
  for (j in loopValues){
    dataframesq3[[i]] <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,j,rep=TRUE)))
    }   
}

print(dataframesq3)
```

Currently, I get 5 data frames with 10 columns each and 1000 rows each instead of one of reach of the 5 above links.

Comment: This is a lazy evaluation problem. You already have several suggested solutions.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. I was able to test all the provided answers and additionally used the help here to work on the next task, which was using a loop to run linear regression and print the results. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just refer to the index of `loopValues` with `i` and use a single loop:

```r
y <- 5
loopValues <- c(100,200,500,800,1000)
dataframesq3 <- vector("list", y)

for (i in 1:y) {
    dataframesq3[[i]] <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,loopValues[i],rep=TRUE)))
}

print(dataframesq3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach without a loop:

```
loopValues <- c(100,200,500,800,1000)
dataframesq3 <- lapply(loopValues, function(x) data.frame(replicate(10, rbinom(x, 1, .5))))
```

Comment: Do you think `lapply` is not looping?

Comment: Should have said without using a `for` loop. Of course it loops but does so without having to create an object to accumulate results or an index. All of that overhead is built into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the probabilities for 0 and 1 across columns are equal, you could create *m*n* matrices.

```
n <- 10
loopValues <- c(100, 200, 500, 800, 1000)

set.seed(42)
r <- lapply(loopValues, \(m) data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, m*n, replace=TRUE), m, n)))

stopifnot(all.equal(r, dataframesq3))  ## refers to @lhs's solution
```

Or, since you want a `for` loop:

```
r <- vector("list", y)
set.seed(42)
for (i in seq_along(loopValues)) {
  r[[i]] <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, loopValues[i]*n, replace=TRUE), loopValues[i], n))
}

stopifnot(all.equal(r, dataframesq3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is in the inner loop :

> for (j in loopValues){
> dataframesq3[[i]] <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,j,rep=TRUE)))
> }

which makes 5 data.frames with sizes (100,10) , (200,10) , (500,10) , (800,10) , (1000,10) in each iteration but Unfortunately it binds the results to the same name "dataframesq3[['1]] for example" but returns the the last one with size (1000,10).

so we have here 25 data.frames 5 in each iteration
but the last one in each iteration binds to our list .

with respect to [limey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13434871/limey) comment it not about lazy evaluation which appears in another situations

and heres another approach using for loop :

```r
y <- 5

dataframesq3 <- vector("list", y)
loopValues <- c(100, 200, 500, 800, 1000)
j <- 1L
for (i in loopValues) {
  dataframesq3[[j]] <-
    data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:1, i, rep = TRUE)))
  j <- j + 1
}


print(dataframesq3)
#> [[1]]
#>     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#> 1    0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 2    0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 3    0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
#> 4    0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 5    1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 6    1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 7    0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 8    1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 9    1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 10   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 11   0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 12   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 13   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 14   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 15   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 16   1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 17   0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 18   1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 19   1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 20   1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 21   0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 22   1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 23   1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 24   0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 25   1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 26   1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 27   0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 28   0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 29   1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 30   0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 31   1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 32   0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 33   1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 34   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 35   0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 36   0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   0
#> 37   0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
#> 38   1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 39   1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 40   0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 41   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 42   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 43   1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 44   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 45   1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 46   0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 47   0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
#> 48   1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 49   0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 50   1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   1
#> 51   1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   1
#> 52   1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 53   1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 54   1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 55   1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 56   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 57   1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 58   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 59   0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 60   0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   0
#> 61   0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 62   1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 63   1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 64   1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 65   1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
#> 66   1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 67   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 68   0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 69   1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 70   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 71   0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 72   0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 73   1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 74   0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 75   1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 76   0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 77   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 78   0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 79   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 80   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 81   1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 82   0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 83   0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 84   1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 85   1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 86   1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 87   1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 88   1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 89   0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 90   0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 91   0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 92   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 93   1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 94   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 95   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 96   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 97   0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 98   0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   0
#> 99   0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 100  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#> 1    1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 2    0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 3    0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   0
#> 4    0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 5    1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 6    0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 7    0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 8    0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 9    1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 10   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 11   1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   0
#> 12   0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 13   0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 14   0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 15   1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 16   0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 17   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 18   1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 19   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
#> 20   0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 21   1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 22   1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1   1
#> 23   0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 24   1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 25   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0
#> 26   0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 27   1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 28   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 29   1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 30   1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 31   1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 32   1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 33   0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 34   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 35   1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 36   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
#> 37   1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 38   0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 39   0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
#> 40   0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 41   1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 42   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 43   1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 44   1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 45   1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 46   0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 47   1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 48   1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 49   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 50   1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 51   0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
#> 52   1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 53   0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 54   1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 55   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 56   1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 57   1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 58   1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 59   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 60   0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 61   0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 62   0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 63   1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 64   0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 65   1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1   1
#> 66   1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0   1
#> 67   1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 68   1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 69   1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 70   0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 71   1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 72   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 73   0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 74   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 75   1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 76   1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 77   1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 78   1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 79   1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
#> 80   0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 81   1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 82   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
#> 83   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 84   0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 85   1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 86   0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 87   1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 88   1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 89   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 90   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 91   1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 92   1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 93   1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   1
#> 94   0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 95   0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 96   1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 97   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 98   0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 99   0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
#> 100  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 101  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 102  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 103  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 104  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 105  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 106  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 107  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 108  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1   0
#> 109  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
#> 110  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 111  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 112  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 113  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 114  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 115  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 116  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 117  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 118  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 119  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 120  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 121  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 122  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 123  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 124  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 125  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 126  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 127  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
#> 128  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 129  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 130  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   0
#> 131  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 132  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 133  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 134  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 135  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 136  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 137  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 138  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 139  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 140  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 141  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 142  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   1
#> 143  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 144  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 145  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 146  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 147  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 148  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 149  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0   1
#> 150  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 151  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 152  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 153  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 154  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 155  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 156  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 157  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0   0
#> 158  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 159  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 160  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 161  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 162  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 163  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
#> 164  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 165  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 166  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 167  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 168  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 169  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 170  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 171  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 172  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 173  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 174  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 175  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
#> 176  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 177  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 178  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   1
#> 179  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 180  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 181  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 182  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 183  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 184  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 185  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 186  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 187  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 188  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 189  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 190  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 191  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 192  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 193  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 194  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 195  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 196  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1   0
#> 197  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 198  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 199  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 200  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#> 1    1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 2    0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 3    1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 4    1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 5    0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 6    0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 7    0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 8    0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 9    0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   1
#> 10   1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 11   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 12   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 13   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 14   1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 15   0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1   1
#> 16   0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 17   0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
#> 18   1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 19   0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 20   1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 21   1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 22   0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   1
#> 23   1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 24   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 25   0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 26   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 27   0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 28   1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 29   1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
#> 30   0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 31   1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 32   1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 33   0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 34   1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 35   1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 36   1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 37   1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 38   0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 39   1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
#> 40   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 41   1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 42   1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 43   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 44   1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 45   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 46   1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 47   1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 48   0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   0
#> 49   1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 50   0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 51   0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1   0
#> 52   1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 53   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 54   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 55   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 56   1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
#> 57   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 58   1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 59   1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 60   1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 61   1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
#> 62   1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 63   0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 64   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 65   1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0   1
#> 66   0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 67   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 68   0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 69   1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 70   1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   1
#> 71   1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 72   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 73   1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 74   1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 75   0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 76   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 77   1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 78   0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
#> 79   1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 80   1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 81   1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 82   1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 83   1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 84   0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 85   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 86   1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 87   0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 88   0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 89   0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
#> 90   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 91   1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 92   1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 93   0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0   1
#> 94   0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
#> 95   0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 96   0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 97   0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 98   1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 99   1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 100  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 101  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   0
#> 102  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 103  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 104  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 105  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 106  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 107  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 108  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 109  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 110  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 111  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 112  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 113  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 114  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 115  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 116  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 117  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 118  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 119  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 120  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 121  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0
#> 122  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 123  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 124  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 125  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 126  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 127  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 128  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 129  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 460  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 461  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 462  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
#> 463  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 464  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 465  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 466  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 467  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 468  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 469  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 470  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 471  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 472  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 473  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 474  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 475  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 476  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1   1
#> 477  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 478  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 479  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 480  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 481  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 482  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
#> 483  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 484  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   0
#> 485  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 486  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 487  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
#> 488  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 489  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 490  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   1
#> 491  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 492  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 493  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 494  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 495  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0   1
#> 496  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 497  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 498  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 499  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
#> 500  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#> 1    1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 2    0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 3    0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 4    1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1   0
#> 5    1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 6    1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1   0
#> 7    0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 8    1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   0
#> 9    1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   0
#> 10   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 11   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 12   1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 13   0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   0
#> 14   1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 15   1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 16   0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 17   0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 18   1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 19   1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 20   0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
#> 21   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
#> 22   1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 23   1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
#> 24   0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 25   1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 26   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 27   0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   0
#> 28   1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 29   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 30   1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 31   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 32   1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 33   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 34   1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   0
#> 35   1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 36   0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 37   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 38   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 39   1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 40   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 41   1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 42   1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 43   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 44   1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 45   0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   0
#> 46   0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 47   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 48   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 49   0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 50   1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 51   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 52   0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 53   1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 54   0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 55   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 56   1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 57   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
#> 58   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 59   1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 60   1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 61   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 62   1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 63   1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 64   1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 65   1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 66   0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 67   1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 68   0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 69   0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 70   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 71   1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 72   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 73   1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 74   1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 75   1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 76   1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 77   0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 78   1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 79   0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 80   1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 81   1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 82   1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 83   1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 84   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   0
#> 85   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 86   0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 87   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 88   0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 89   0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 90   0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 91   0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 92   0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 93   0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   0
#> 94   1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 95   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 96   0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 97   0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 98   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
#> 99   1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 100  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
> 776  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 777  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   0
#> 778  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 779  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 780  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 781  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 782  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 783  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 784  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 785  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 786  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 787  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 788  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
#> 789  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 790  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
#> 791  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 792  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 793  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 794  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 795  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   0
#> 796  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   0
#> 797  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 798  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 799  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0
#> 800  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#> 1     1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0   1
#> 2     1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1   0
#> 3     1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 4     0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 5     1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 6     1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 7     1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
#> 8     0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 9     0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 10    1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 11    1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
#> 12    0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 13    1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 14    1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
#> 15    1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 16    1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 17    0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 18    0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 19    1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#> 20    1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
#> 21    1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 22    1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   1
#> 23    0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 24    1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1   1
#> 25    0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 26    0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 27    1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 28    0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0   1
#> 29    0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 30    1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 31    0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 32    0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 33    0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
#> 34    1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 35    1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 36    0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 37    0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 38    1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 39    1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 40    0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 41    1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 42    0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   0
#> 43    0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   1
#> 44    0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1   1
#> 45    1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 46    0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 47    1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   0
#> 48    0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 49    0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 50    1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   1
#> 51    1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 52    0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 53    0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0   0
#> 54    0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
#> 55    0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 56    1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
#> 57    1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 58    0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 59    1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
#> 60    0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   0
#> 61    1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 62    0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 63    1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
#> 64    1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1   0
#> 65    0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   0
#> 66    1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   1
#> 67    0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
#> 68    0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 69    1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
#> 70    1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
#> 71    0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
#> 72    1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 73    1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 74    0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 75    1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   0
#> 76    1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 77    1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1   1
#> 78    0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0   1
#> 79    0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0   1
#> 80    0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 81    1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 82    0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0   1
#> 83    1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
#> 84    1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0   1
#> 85    1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 86    1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
#> 87    1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
#> 88    1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   1
#> 89    0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
#> 90    0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
#> 91    0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 92    0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 93    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
#> 94    0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
#> 95    0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   0
#> 96    1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 97    0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1   0
#> 98    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   0
#> 99    0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
#> 100   1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   0
#> 101   0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0   0
#> 644   1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
#> 645   1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   1
#> 646   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
#> 647   0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   0
#> 648   1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0   1
#> 649   1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
#> 650   1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
#> 651   1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
#> 652   1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
#> 993   0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
#> 994   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
#> 995   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
#> 996   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
#> 997   1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   1
#> 998   1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
#> 999   0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   0
#> 1000  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1   0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>